# How to display returned Object list from AdminController to Admin view in asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have configured 2 method in the AdministractionController that basically will collect all locked account and the other method should unlock an accounts once the user id is passed to it

```
public bool unlockUserById(String userId)
    {

        UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCount(userId);

        if (UserManager.IsLockedOut(userId) == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

//Collect Locked Accounts
 public List<Object> getAllLockedUserList()
        { 
        List<Object> lockedUser = new List<Object>();

            foreach (var user in databaseContext.Users)
            {
                 if(UserManager.IsLockedOut(user.Id))
                {
                    lockedUser.Add(databaseContext.Users);
                }


        }
            return lockedUser;
        }
```

Basically , in the admin control panel View , I would like to display the lockedUser list with buttons next to each locked user that once it's called

I don't know how to do that in MVC5 asp.net

so far this is my view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Hello Admin - Index</h2>
```

Comment: Your GET method needs to return a `List<User>` (not `object`) which is a list of your users. In that view generate a form for each user containing a submit button and pass the users ID to a POST method that calls your method to unlock that user (but it might be better to have one form containing a checkboxlist so that you can unlock multiple users in one action)

Comment: In getAllLockedUserList return some kind of data and view to the user so they can select which ones to unlock. Then have another action in your controller to take the ones they have selected so you can unlock them.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know , that was for testing purposes . I'm not going to leave it an object list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
@model IEnumerable<yournamespace.Models.IdentityUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>
<div>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {    
        <tr>           
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>

                <td>                        

                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit |", "UpdateUser", new { id =  item.Id}) 
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id =  item.Id}) 
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id =  item.Id})                      
               </td>           
        </tr>
    }

</div>
```

also you can check microsoft refrence :

[ASP.Net MVC Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)

Comment: I have a question , the list is : List<IdentityUser> lockoutUsers = new List<IdentityUser>(); ......do you how to return the model to the html page?